# how to use bind event with Text Widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I tried to call press_space() while  pressing space key in Text widget  but massage error say  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' i used python 2.7

```
import nltk
root=Tk()
txt=Tkinter.Text(root,font=('arial',30,'bold'),bd=5,           bg="grey",foreground="red",width="31",height="5").grid(columnspan=50,rowspan=30, column=0)
txt.bind('<space>', press_space)

def press_space():
          print ('Hello world')
```

Comment: You need to call `grid` on a new line like `txt.grid(...)` also bind passes an event argument to callback function, so you need to change `def press_space()` to either `def press_space(event)` or `def press_space(*args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very popular mistake

```
var = Widget(...).grid()
```

It assigns to `var` value returned by `grid()` - `None` - so later you get `None.bind()`

You have to do it in two lines

```
var = Widget(...)
var.grid()
```

After that `bind()` will work correctly.

---

**BTW:** `bind()` executes function with argument `event` which you have to receive.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def press_space(event):
    #print(event)
    #print( dir(event) )
    print('Hello world')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.grid()

txt.bind('<space>', press_space)

root.mainloop()
```